# two machines with thingsboard connected to the same database is possible?

Tags: azure, cloud, iot, thingsboard

I'm deploying Thingsboard CE on Azure. For availability and resiliency reasons, I would like to have two VMs working simultaneously connected to the same database.

Is there any way to do this, is this possible?

I also welcome tips on how to securely host Thingsboard in the cloud.

I managed to do it as follows:

I created a VM and connected it to the database, then created a copy of the VM. That is, two VMs connected to the same database.

Errors:

If my device is connected to VM1 and I am accessing the dashboard through VM2, the data is not automatically updated, I need to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, it is possible to have two machines with ThingsBoard connected to the same database.

1. Use a database like `PostgreSQL` for this.
2. And configure `ThingsBoard` to use the replicated database.
3. And configure your load balancer to distribute traffic between the two machines.

[image]

Providing load balancing for the 2 VMS to access the DB.

[image]

To keep `ThingsBoard` secure in the cloud.

- Use a dedicated VM for ThingsBoard.
- Enable two-factor authentication.
- Use a firewall to restrict access to ThingsBoard.
- And also keep ThingsBoard up to date with the latest security patches.

For [Security Fundamentals](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/security/fundamentals/paas-deployments.md) and [Security best-practices](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/security/fundamentals/best-practices-and-patterns.md)

> And for the error you are getting, you need to make sure that the two VMs are using the same data synchronization mechanism.

This can be achieved with distributed cache, like Redis. When a device sends a data point to VM1, the data point is also sent to the cache. When VM2 requests the data point, it gets it from the cache. This ensures that both VMs have the latest data.

> Another approach for the error is

To use a message broker, like RabbitMQ. When a device sends a data point to VM1, the data point is sent to the message broker. VM2 can then subscribe to the topic for the data point and receive it as soon as it is sent.

For more information, refer to the [Blog](https://thingsboard.io/products/paas/domains/).

Comment: 1.I am using postgresql DB.
2.I configured the two VM to connect to the same DB.
3.I configured the load balancer.

1 solution:
About the distributed cache, I don't know how to configure it, and I'm not finding information to configure it. It is possible to perform this configuration without performing the cluster mode architecture.

2 solution:
I used a queue service and it solved the problem, however the panel showed different information from each other, just refreshing the page to show the same information.
the load balancer used was azure service bus.

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: You can use a queue service to solve the problem of load balancing. However, the panel showed different information from each other, just refreshing the page to show the same information. Azure Service Bus is a load balancer that can be used to distribute messages among multiple independent systems.